# Error while using iab in vimrc

Tags: vim

I need to convert

`for(int` to for `(int`

automatically in my vim editor.

So I have written following statement in my vimrc

```
iab for(int    for (int
```

but its giving following error

```
line  158:
E474: Invalid argument
```

What is the reason for this error ??

Also How can I write a general statement which will convert

```
 for(int to for (int
 for(;; to for (;;  etc...
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 types of abbreviations:

- full-id The abbreviation contains only of `'iskeyword'` characters.
- end-id  The abbreviation ends with a `'iskeyword'` character but all other characters are not keyword characters
- non-id The abbreviation ends with a non-keyword character, the other characters may be of any type (excluding white-space).

(from the help `:h abbreviations`, there are examples for each type in the help).

Neither of those types is `for(int`. So this can't be used as an abbreviation. You could theoretically tweak the `iskeyword` setting to make it valid, but that will most likely have other non-intended consequences that will do more harm than good.

See the help `:h 'iskeyword'` for an explanation what the keyword setting is for.